# if statement checking user input always goes to else branch

Tags: python, if-statement

I want the user to be able to select a value from certain choices. If they select a valid choice, the console will print "Are you sure?", if not it will print "Please select from...".

```
Shutter_Speed = (1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0)
Choose_Shutter_Speed = input ("Select Shutter Interval: ")

if Shutter_Speed in (1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0):
    print ("Are you sure? ")

else:
    print ("Please select from 1.0, 2.0, 5.0 or 10.0 seconds")
```

When I run this code, no matter what I type in as the input, it will run the 'else' statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that your `if` statement tests against `Shutter_Speed`, but the user's input is saved in `Choose_Shutter_Speed`. Besides that, you'll probably want to use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)s (or possibly just strings) to represent shutter speeds, not floats.

Comment: Also, `Choose_Shutter_Speed` is a string, just like anything you get from `input`, and you're trying to compare it to integers. That will always fail. Use `int(input())`.

Comment: It's good practice to save `UpperCase` words for class names only, and have variables conform to the PEP8 style. Otherwise, as you can see, it's confusing (SO highlights them as if they are class names, not variables)

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, `input` will perform parsing in Python 2. It returns a string in Python3.

Answer (score 3):

Your user input is stored in `Choose_Shuttle_Speed`, but you are reading from the variable `Shuttle_Speed`.

```
Shutter_Speed = (1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0)
Choose_Shutter_Speed = input ("Select Shutter Interval: ")

if Choose_Shutter_Speed in (1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0):
    print ("Are you sure? ")

else:
    print ("Please select from 1.0, 2.0, 5.0 or 10.0 seconds")
```

Also, as written, you are not using `Shuttle_Speed` variable at all, you can simply remove it entirely or use it in the way that Matthew suggested.

Comment: This wont work unless you parse to float.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Got it all working now just the way I was aiming for. I was basing my script on a similar one elsewhere which is probably why it went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you are looking for is this

```
if Choose_Shutter_Speed in Shutter_Speed
```

That will check to see if the input is the acceptable values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a dream.